# Error with using Session in SP2010

Tags: development, session

I have got a problem with using Session at Sharepoint 2010.

I use this code:

```
        Session["Dzien"] = TextBox3.Text;
        Session["Pracownik"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

I put at web.config this lines, and the error still showns:

`<pages enableSessionState="true"`

and next lines:

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
.
.
        <remove name="Session" />
        <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />
.
.
</modules>`

And the Error still showns:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run this Powershell?

```
Enable-SPSessionStateService –DefaultProvision
```

This is also required for enable Session State in Sharepoint ([MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/05/27/using-session-state-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx))